# Div fixa ao diminuir a tela

Tags: html, css, layout

Estou desenvolvendo o seguinte site:

```
 http://173.44.46.62/~bellanap/pedidos.php
```

porem ao diminuir a tela, a div onde está o formulário está quebrando. Ela precisa estar fixa.
Me ajudem?

Comment: O ideal seria usar _media queries_ para mudar o layout conforme o tamanho da tela, mas como solução para o layout em desktop você pode por um `body {min-width: NNNNpx}` no CSS (Sendo que NNNN é a largura mínima que você deseja que o site tenha).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que os teus elementos respondam à largura da tela, tens que trabalhar com unidades de medida baseadas na mesma. O mais prático para o teu caso é trabalhar com percentagens.

Neste caso prático, deverás alterar as larguras fixas em pixeis que tens nos elementos em baixo indicados para os seguintes valores em percentagem:

### CSS

```css
.main{
  width:50%;                          /* estava 925px */
}
.formulario{
  width:82%;                          /* estava 720px */
}
.input{
  width:100%;                         /* estava 720px */
}
.input-tel-email{
  width:46%;                          /* estava 340px */
}
textarea{
  width:100%;
}
```

<sup>Todos as restantes declarações mantêm-se.</sup>

### Resultado

Captura de Tela com cerca de 800 pixeis de largura:

[image: Captura de Tela com cerca de 800 pixeis de largura]

Comment: Oi Zuul! Obrigada por me ajudar. Mas tenho uma dúvida ainda. Preciso que o tamanho da .main seja de 70% e se coloco essa porcentagem, o layout quebra. Digo isso, pois no mobile mesmo sem media querie deve mostrar todo o site. Meu viewport está com 1020px

Comment: @FláviaAmaral Se tudo estiver com percentagens, não vejo como possa _quebrar_, ao definires 70% para a tua `.main`, todos os elementos dentro da mesma deveriam _encolher_ sem problemas. Estive agora a voltar a analisar o teu projecto e reparei que provavelmente aquilo a que te referes é o facto do teu elemento `.main` ter uma `margin-left:310px`, o que não resulta quando reduzes a tela pelo motivo explicado na minha resposta. Deverás aplicar um valor em percentagem também.